# Generate HMAC before sending JSON response with Jackson + Jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I am building a REST API with Jersey and Jackson. I used this tutorial (http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/) to get started with Jackson.

I want to sign the response before sending it. How can I get the JSON string that will be generated so I can sign it?

```
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getTrackInJSON() {

    Track track = new Track();
    track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
    track.setSinger("Metallica");

    String HMAC = HMAC("[secret]", [track.toJson]);

    return Response.status(201).entity(track).header("HMAC", HMAC).build();

}
```

I also want to verify the signature of an incomming request:

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createTrackInJSON(Track track) {

    String rawRequestBody = [how to get the raw request?];

    //get header
    //verify HMAC

    return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

}
```

So my big question is how can get the raw JSON string that will be generated from an object before it will be sent?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Both can be done by by-passing Jersey's default input/output data binding, and using Jackson directly. For that you would declare input to come as either `byte[]` or `InputStream`, and use Jackson's `ObjectMapper.readValue(...)`. And for output you would declare returning `byte[]` (possible within `Response`), and use `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(responsePojo)`. Or, if it is easier to work with Strings (I forget details of how HMAC calculation work), `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(responsePojo)` would give serialization as `String`.